# Apache 2.4 - IF block for different url patterns

Tags: regex, apache, apache2.4

I am trying to create if blocks in one rewrite file and call different rewrite files if a url pattern match

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /category1(.*)$/">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category1.conf
</If>
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /category2/subcategory1(.*)$/">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category21.conf
</ElseIf>
<Else "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /category2/subcategory2(.*)$/">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category22.conf
</Else>
```

Problems i am facing:

1. With first pattern, `/category1(.*)$/`, it allow any url containing category1 instead of urls starts with /category1
2. 2nd & 3rd pattern is not working and giving regex syntax error.

I have tried different syntax without success

1. `m#/category1(.*)$/#i`
2. `m#/\s/category1(.*)$/#i`
3. `m#/\/category1(.*)$/#i`
4. `m#\s/category2\s/sucategory1(.*)$/#i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this code with start anchors added in your regex pattern:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/category1#">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category1.conf
</If>
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/category2/subcategory1#">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category21.conf
</ElseIf>
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/category2/subcategory2#">
    Include conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections_category22.conf
</ElseIf>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion.
1st rule is working fine. 2nd & 3rd is giving syntax error.
Its because of multiple / characters in pattern. I have tried to escape it by using following - m#^/category2\/subcategory2# or m#^/category2\s/subcategory2# but no luck

Comment: Error is: AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /httpd/conf.d/sites/abc/301_redirections.conf

Comment: Problem was in last block. `Else` doesn't support any condition, you needed `ElseIf`. Check updated answer now. Also there is no need to escape `/` when you use `m#...#`